# What path should I give so that contextual filter works

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I am creating on **view page** for which works like `archive` and I am doing it for the **terms** that are used in **Blog**(I am using `blog module`).

I have followed [this](http://www.webbykat.com/2012/02/creating-monthly-archive-block-drupal-7-views) tutorial.

But problem is when I give **CONTEXTUAL FILTERS** to `year+month`, and after that If I open my URL `example.com/blog/201502` it is showing me 404 page.

Where am I lacking ?

**NOTE:** It is working fine in preview which are under view.

Some snap shot regarding this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If I put path something like `blog/%` then It is showing me all the blog post and I want to have Terms.

[image]

If I click on `January 2015` then It should give me following result :

[image]

Please help me.I have tried a lot.Let me know if more information is required.

Comment: How is the contextual filter processing the argument?  How does it know that 201501 is January 2015?  Is it a custom field on the blog?

Comment: I am sorry but I did not get you.There is only one field that I have added and it is term name.You can see it in first pic of my question.

Comment: @Darvanen Why is it give me all the blog entry if I add `%` in the path(example.com/%) ? I have managed the path.But page is showing all the blog entry but in the preview, It is showing me **January 2015**.Do you know the reason behind it ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a node view create a taxonomy view

In that provide two relationships

```
Taxonomy term: Content with term
Taxonomy term: Content using {Name of the taxonomy field in the content type}*
Add a contextual filter of the type Content : Title Use the first relationship for the contextual filter, Make necessary changes in the more option such as change to lover case turn space to dashes etc
Add the required fields from the content with the relationship set to 2)
```

You are good to go.

EDIT : As per the discussion There was another need to also show the nodes under a term and its sub terms.

```
Create a view of the type content.

Add the required fields

Add a contextual filter of the type Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth) and select the depth a value as deep as the hierarchy you have in the taxonomy.
```

Now when you pass the term id as the input it would show all the nodes under that taxonomy term including the child nodes

If you wish to change the url to have the term name instead of the term ID Do the following.

```
In view give the path as taxonomy/term/% this will override the default taxonomy path.

Install Pathauto Module this depends on Tokens module so have to install that as well.

In Configuration -> URL aliases you have a tab called Patters

Set the pattern of the "TAXONOMY TERM PATHS" to what you would like it to be. Make sure that the last value is [term:name] so if you want the path to be category/carrot you should give it as category/[term:name]

If you have already added the taxonomy terms then you would need to do the "BULK UPDATE" which is again a tab on the URL Alias page.
```

Now when you visit the page category/termname you will see all the nodes under the term including the child terms